# SQL create column for every week (Loop?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, join, union

I need to make a report for weekly changes.
This is the code for todays amount

```
SELECT 
[Entry No_],
[Customer No_],
[Posting Date],
[Description],
[Currency Code],
Trans_type = case when [Deposit]=1 then 'Deposit' 
when [Imprest]=1 then 'Imprest' 
else 'Other' end,
A.Amount
 FROM Table1
 LEFT JOIN
 (
 SELECT Distinct [Cust_ Ledger Entry No_],
SUM ([Amount EUR]) as 'amount'
 FROM Table2
 group by [Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
 having
SUM ([Amount EUR]) <> '0'
)A
on [Entry No_] = A.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
Where 
A.Amount is not NULL
```

Code to generate data for previous week is here (adding only where clause):

```
SELECT 
[Entry No_],
[Customer No_],
[Posting Date],
[Description],
[Currency Code],
Trans_type = case when [Deposit]=1 then 'Deposit' 
when [Imprest]=1 then 'Imprest' 
else 'Other' end,
A.Amount
  FROM Table1
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT Distinct [Cust_ Ledger Entry No_],
SUM ([Amount EUR]) as 'amount'
  FROM Table2
  where [posting Date] < '2020-11-23'
  group by [Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
  having
SUM ([Amount EUR]) <> '0'
)A
on [Entry No_] = A.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
Where 
A.Amount is not NULL
```

It would be enough to union both queries and then export to Excel and make pivot, but problem is that I need results of last 50 weeks. Is there any smart way to avoid union 50 tables and run one simple code to generate weekly report?

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help yo here, however, I see no reason for any `UNION` queries here; I suspect you just need aggregates and `GROUP BY` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

it might be easier with sample, but I don't know how to paste table here..

Maybe it is true, i dont need union here, and group by would be enough, but it stills sounds difficult for me :)

Ok. Lets say table has such headers: *Project* | *Country* | *date* | *amount*

The code below returns amount for todays date

```
Select 
Project,
SUM(amount)
From Table
Group by Project
```

I actually need todays date and also the results of previous weeks (What was the result on November 22 (week 47), November 15 (week 46) and so on.. total 50 weeks from todays date).

Code for previous week amount is here:

```
Select 
Project,
SUM(amount)
From Table
Where Date < '2020.11.23'
Group by Project
```

So my idea was to create create 50 codes and join the results together, but i am sure it is a better way to do this. Besides i dont want to edit this query every week and add a new date for it.

So any ideas, to make my life easier?

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood your requirement correctly, all you need to do is extract the week from the date e.g.

```
Select 
Project,
datepart(week, date),
SUM(amount)
From Table
Where Date < '2020.11.23'
Group by Project, datepart(week, date)
```